# Synchronize scrollbars in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, scroll

Is there any way to synchronize scrollbars in VS2010? For instance, if you have two files that are nearly identical and you are trying to diff them using vertical tab groups, is there a setting that will allow you to synchronize the scrolling in both?

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't work out a way to do it in VS but if all you want to do is compare you could always use Notepad++, which is an awesome free text editor. Get that and copy and paste your code into two different tabs in NP++, then right click one of the tabs and choose 'Move to Other View'. You should then have the two side by side. Scroll both of them to the top and then click 'View -> Synchronize Vertical Scrolling' and that'll keep them synched and you can do easy side by side comparisons.

Hope that helps!

Comment: funny you mention this because this is exactly what i did back in may when i asked this :)

Comment: Had a feeling you might have resolved it, I just hoped someone else who came along would find it useful! NP++ is a lifesaver, I always use it for checking Javascript and find those annoying missing parenthesis as VS is useless with Javscript. There is a button in VS under View called Synchronize Views but its always greyed out on mine :/

Answer (score 1):

Synchronized scrollbars are not part of VS2010.

[**Here you can vote for them!**](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/671304/implement-synchronized-scrolling)

Comment: Hey I have raised that bug/feature. It is good to know that there are other people who want this functionality. It is sad, though, that this has been closed as Won'tFix.

Answer (score 1):

Is better to take [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to compare two files.

1. Open WinMerge, Do "Ctrl+N", then two blank pages will open,
2. Copy-paste the code one in the left, another in the right page,
3. Press F5 to see the differences.

You also may do not do the step (3) if you just want to compare manually side by side, using synchronous scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

You could always set the selectedindex and then set the top on all of your listboxes for the "effect"...